# Mongos auto start script for Linux

Tags: mongodb

I have two mongos server in a production environment. I want to start mongos automatically when the server reboots. I tried several options to achieve this, but couldn't. I have three config servers.

Comment: The repo comes with a init script, just install form repo: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/

Comment: Replica set and Config servers works fine with the default init and config file. But mongos(Query routers) not working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way to get it accomplished.
If you are using Linux , it should have 'crontab' installed – a utility which runs cron job.
You need to execute the following command (only once) to automate run of mongos on every start/re-start of your linux machine. Here we are editing the crontab to add a cron job(run script) on every reboot/boot event.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Add a line like this to it:

```
@reboot /path/to/script
```

The script should invoke path/to/mongo/bin/mongos -options

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I would like to use the default config file   for this. Is there any possibility?.

Comment: Default config file as a argument when you start mongos? Yes, that should work.

Comment: Can you elaborate little more. I mean what all changes I will have to make.

Comment: What do you want to use the default config file for??

Comment: What I assume is, if I can update the configdb settings in the default config file "/etc/mongod.conf". It will be more easy and flexible rather than the cron job.